# Hopcroft's Algorithm for Minimization of Deterministic Finite State Automaton

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, algorithm

#### Background

Given a deterministic finite state automaton, [Hopcroft's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft's_algorithm) is a $O(n \log(n))$ algorithm for finding an automaton that generates the same language with a minimal number of vertices. We can represent an automaton $\mathcal{A}$ as a directed labeled graph $\mathcal{A}=(Q,F, \Sigma, \delta)$: a set of vertices/states $Q$, a set of fail vertices/states $F\subseteq Q$, an alphabet of edge labels $\Sigma$, and a collection of labeled edges $\delta:Q\times \Sigma\to Q$.

Copying the pseudocode from wikipedia, we generate a partition $P$ of the vertex set $Q$ by repeatedly splitting the current partition, while updating a waiting set $W$ by which we need to split/refine the current partition.

```
P := {F, Q \ F};
W := {F};
while (W is not empty) do
     choose and remove a set A from W
     for each c in Σ do
          let X be the set of states for which a transition on c leads to a state in A
           for each set Y in P for which X ∩ Y is nonempty and Y \ X is nonempty do
                replace Y in P by the two sets X ∩ Y and Y \ X
                if Y is in W
                    replace Y in W by the same two sets
                else
                    if |X ∩ Y| <= |Y \ X|
                         add X ∩ Y to W
                    else
                         add Y \ X to W
          end;
     end;
end;
```

I'm having some issues converting the numerous nested loops into clean Mathematica/functorial code. A naive, faithful implementation `While[...For[...For[...If[...,....,If[...,...,...]]]]]` is just as slow as one would expect.

#### My implementation

I'm storing graphs as a list of directed edges, e.g.,

```
g1={{0 -> 0, 0}, {0 -> 0, 1}, {1 -> 2, 0}, {1 -> 3, 1}, 
    {2 -> 2, 0}, {2 -> 3, 1}, {3 -> 0, 1}, {3 -> 1, 0}};
```

where the vertex $0$ is the sole fail state.

My first helper function creates a table (indexed by the alphabet) of associations that return all vertices which have an edge bearing the appropriate label leading to the desired vertex, i.e., $\delta^{-1}(x, e)$:

```
incomingVertices[graph_, vertexList_, alphabet_] := 
    Table[
       With[{relevant = Select[graph, #[[2]] == a &]}, 
            Merge[
             {Thread[relevant[[All, 1, 2]] -> relevant[[All, 1, 1]]], 
           Thread[Complement[vertexList, 
          DeleteDuplicates@relevant[[All, 1, 2]]] -> Nothing]},
     Join]
    ],
   {a, alphabet}]
```

A bit kludgy, but it only needs to run once.

```
incomingVertices[g1, VertexList[g1[[All,1]]], Union[g1[[All,2]]]]
(*{<|0 -> {0}, 2 -> {1, 2}, 1 -> {3}, 3 -> {}|>, 
    <|0 -> {0, 3},  3 -> {1, 2}, 1 -> {}, 2 -> {}|>} *)
```

## Edit: Per Daniel Lichtblau and Henrik Schumacher in the comments, it appears that this implementation is $O(n^2)$ or worse

My main function, with the general structure `While[...Do[...Table[]; Table[];..]...]`, is then given by

```
hopcroft[graph_] := Module[
{alphabet = Union@graph[[All, 2]],
 vertexList = Sort@VertexList@graph[[All, 1]],
 W = {{0}},
 inc, part, partby, newtopartby, inW, notinW, newpartinW, newpartnotinW, newtopartbyinW, newtopartbynotinW, X},
 part = {DeleteCases[vertexList, 0], {0}};
 inc = incomingVertices[graph, vertexList, alphabet];
 Clear[vertexList];
 While[Length@W > 0,
    partby = First@W;
    W = Rest[W];
    Do[X = Union@Flatten[partby /. inc[[index]]];
        inW=Intersection[part, W];
        notinW=Complement[part, inW];
        newpartinW=Table[{Intersection[Y, X], Complement[Y, X]}, {Y, inW}];
        newpartnotinW=Table[{Intersection[Y, X], Complement[Y, X]}, {Y, notinW}];
        part=DeleteCases[Level[newpartinW~Join~newpartnotinW, {-2}], {}];
        newtopartbyinW=Level[W /. Association[Thread[inW -> newpartinW]], {-2}];
        newtopartbynotinW= MinimalBy[#,Length,1]&/@Select[newpartnotinW,FreeQ[#, {}] &];
        W = DeleteCases[Level[newtopartbyinW~Join~newtopartbynotinW, {-2}], {}];,
{index, Length@alphabet}]
   ];
  part]
```

The general philosophy of my implementation is that we need to handle pieces of the partition differently depending on whether or not they are in the waiting set `W`, hence the initial `inW = ...` and `notinW=...`. Similarly, my prototyping lead to it seeming to be more efficient to just compute all the intersections and complements at once, rather than implementing a bunch of boolean logic to handle each element of partitions independently.

#### Timing results

For a small graph, this runs quite fast:

```
RepeatedTiming[hopcroft[g1]]
(*{0.000310, {{0}, {3}, {1, 2}}}*)
```

However, it starts grinding to a halt for large graphs. For example, the following sort of graph is generally considered a worst case scenario for the algorithm, needing to refine the partition until each vertex is distinct:

```
bigGraph = With[{n = 10^3, alph = 3}, 
           Flatten[#, 1]&@
           Table[{i -> If[i + j > n, 0, i + j], j}, {i, n}, {j, alph}]];

RepeatedTiming[hopcroft[bigGraph];]
(*{3.663, Null} *)
```

With `n=10^4` instead, I get

```
Timing[hopcroft[bigGraph];]
(*{362.041, Null}*)
```

My ideal end usage is even worse, with automata that have $O(10^5)$ vertices and $O(10^6)$ edges.

#### Questions

1. How can I speed this up? Profiling my code, it seems to spend by far the majority of the time computing an obscene number of intersections. Since this is already such a low-level built in function, I'm not sure what I can do to significantly speed this up.
2. I have access to some clustered computing resources (my desktop has 4 physical cores, free reign on a server with 32 physical cores, scheduled access to a cluster with over 1000 physical cores). However, I don't see a great way to parallelize this algorithm, as the partition will (usually) get updated with each lap of the `Do[X = ..., {index, Length@alphabet}]` loop. Naively replacing all the `Table[..]` commands with `ParallelTable[...]` seems to actually slow down computation, presumably since the individual computations are so fast and we gain a lot of overhead of pushing data to/from the slave cores. It is, however, quite entertaining to watch the `ParallelKernelStatus` window while this happens! Any thoughts on how we can efficiently distribute this problem?
3. There are implementations of Hopcroft's algorithm implemented in C/C++/Python floating around---in many ways, the algorithm seems built for procedural languages. Worst case, I could always run an external call. However, I have a preference towards staying within Mathematica---especially if we can efficiently parallelize it.

### Edits:

Hopcroft's original 1971 paper can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-417750-5.50022-1), but is unfortunately paywalled. There are several other analyses and descriptions of the algorithm in the literature as well, primarily explanatory or focused on showing that it is indeed $O(n \log(n))$ and $\Omega(n \log(n))$ or analyzing run time comparisons to several other algorithms that have worse theoretical complexity, but can slightly outperform Hopcroft in some cases.

#### Explanation of My Implementation

I have also tried to present my code with generally the same variable names as in the pseudocode (particularly `W`, `X`, and `Y`). The main change between the pseudocode an my implementation concerns converting the innermost `for ...` loop with its multiple booleans into just computing all of the intersections / set complements and then updating the partition `part` and the waiting set `W` accordingly. Specifically, my code handles these operations with the innermost `Do` loop:

1. `X = Union@Flatten[partby /. inc[[index]]];` Sets `X` as the set of all vertices that have an edge labeled by `alphabet[[index]]`. We need to update the current partition `part` and waiting set `W` based on the intersections / complements with `X` of each set `Y` in `part` and `W`
2. `inW=Intersection[part, W]; notinW=Complement[part, inW];` breaks the current partition `part` into two chunks: those that also appear in the waiting list, and those that don't. Rather than using booleans later to handle these separately, I sepearate them out now.
3. `newpartinW=Table[{Intersection[Y, X], Complement[Y, X]}, {Y, inW}];
    newpartnotinW=Table[{Intersection[Y, X], Complement[Y, X]}, {Y, notinW}];` For each set $Y$ in the partition `part`, we will eventually replace $Y$ by $Y \cap X$ and $Y \setminus X$. Note that one of these will often be empty the empty list `{}`, so we will garbage collect out these later.
4. `part=DeleteCases[Level[newpartinW~Join~newpartnotinW, {-2}], {}];` returns the new partition. Regardless of whether `Y` is in the waiting set or `W` or not, we replace `Y` in `part` by $\{ Y \cap X, Y\setminus X\}$, use `Level[ ..., {-2}]` to flatten out a level, and then remove all the empty lists with `DeleteCases[ ..., {}]`.
5. `newtopartbyinW=Level[W /. Association[Thread[inW -> newpartinW]], {-2}];` If a set $Y$ is in the waiting set $W$, then we need to replace $Y$ in $W$ by $Y \cap X$ and $Y \setminus X$. Since `inW` contains all elements of the partition that are in `W` and `newpartinW` contains the image of each under the mapping $Y \mapsto \{ Y \cap X, Y \setminus X \}$, we use `Thread[inW -> newpartinW]` to get a list of the form `{{Y_1 -> {Y_1 \cap X, Y_1 \setminus X}, {Y_2 ->{Y_2 \cap X, Y_2 \setminus X}, ...}` and then update `W` by acting on it by this association. Note that there will again be many empty lists `{}` (which will later get removed). Also note that if $w \in W$ and $w \not \in$`part`, then it will be unchanged, i.e., we retain the previous waiting list `W` and only split the ones that are elements of the current partition.
6. `newtopartbynotinW= MinimalBy[#,Length,1]&/@Select[newpartnotinW,FreeQ[#, {}] &];` This line takes care of the bulk of the booleans `Else[ If[ ..., ..., Else[...]]]`. The `Select[newpartnotinW,FreeQ[#, {}] &]` picks out only the pairs ${Y_i \cap X, Y_i \setminus X}$ when $Y_i$ is actually split by $X$ (if a set $Y_i$ isn't split by $X$, then we don't need to add anything to `W`. From this list of non-empty pairs, `MinimalBy[#, Length,1]&/@ ...` maps over the list of pairs and returns whichever is shorter, with the `MinimalBy[...,...,1]` ensuring that only one list from each pair is returned in the event of a tie in length.
7. `W = DeleteCases[Level[newtopartbyinW~Join~newtopartbynotinW, {-2}], {}];` We redefine the waiting set `W` to update all the changes we need to make. Note that we will loop back through the `Do[..., {index, Length@alphabet}]` several more times before stepping out to pick a new set with which to partition by. The new waiting list `W` contains sublists from three sources:

   - Those that were already in `W` and are not elements of the partition. These are in `newtopartbyinW` as they are left unchanged by `W/.Associtation[...]`
   - Those that were already in `W` and are elements of the partition. These are in `newtopartbyinW` as they were updated by the replacement `W/.Association[...]`
   - Those that were not in `W` already. These come from `newtopartbynotinW`. Note that we only needed to add in the shorter of $Y_i \cap X$ and $Y_i \setminus X$, as splitting by a set $X$ is the same as splitting by $X^c$.

We then repeat the `Do` loop for the next splitting set `X`, then break out and choose and delete a new set `topartby` from the waiting set `W`.

The key observation that I had regarding this level of optimization was that at any stage in the algorithm, the current partition `part` (or `P`) has to satisfy containing every element of the vertex list (i.e., `Union[part]==VertexList[graph[[All,1]]`), and the partition is in fact a partition of the vertex list (i.e., it is composed of non-intersecting lists). As such, updating a set $Y \in P$ has no side-effects on other elements of the partition and updating `W` based upon the splitting of a set `Y` has no side-effects on the other elements of `W` (up to the specific order of the waiting list/ queue `W`). We can see this most clearly in that the innermost `for` loop of the pseudocode doesn't require an order with which to split each of the $Y \in P$. Thus, I have done things in the order "split the $Y$'s that are also in `W` first" and then "split the $Y$'s thare aren't in `W`" last.

#### Some Musings Towards Optimization

Here's some ideas I've had, but haven't quite been able to figure out how to connect the dots.

- There does seem to be some research in the literature into the effect of different strategies for processing the waiting list / queue `W`, i.e., FIFO vs. FILO vs. Shortest first vs. Longest first, etc. While it does seem to make some difference, the effect is a bit underwhelming (<5% gains under optimal conditions IIRC), so I've elected to just take `topartby=First[W]; W=Rest[W];` out of convenience.
- If an element of the partition gets split apart enough to the point that it only contains a single vertex (i.e., `{..., {v_i}, ....}`), then there's no need to keep keep recomputing $\{ \{v_i\} \cap X, \{v_i\} \setminus X \}$, as one of them will trivially be empty. So perhaps some logic to set such sets aside and treat them differently? Note that singleton sets in the waiting list `W` are fine and necessary.
- The current structure takes a set `X = Union@Flatten@(partby/.inc[[index]])`, updates the partition, updates the waiting list, and then loops back around to take `X=Union@Flatten(partby/.inc[[index + 1]]`. This seems like its perhaps the prone to effective parallelization, sending each core off to compute the new partition and waiting list for its given index. I.e., something like `ParallelTable[...., {index, Length@alphabet}]` instead of `Do[...]`. I haven't been able to envision how to combine back these results without computing a whole mess of pairwise intersections/complements. Similarly, the idea of distributing an element of the waiting list to each core feels productive, until its time to combine all of the results back into a single partition and single waiting list.
- All the constant reassignments `W=...` and `part=...` are generally slow, as opposed to some faster data structure that doesn't require copying the entire list each time.
- While `Intersection` and `Complement` are already fast built-ins, perhaps there's savings to be had by using a compiled function which knows that it will only ever act integer lists? Similarly, $Y \setminus X = Y \setminus (Y \cap X)$. Since $|Y \cap X| \leq | Y|$ and presumably `Complement[Y, #]` will be faster with a shorter list in the second component, I've tried using functions along the lines of `With[{YcapX = Intersection[Y,X]},{YcapX, Complement[Y,YcapX]}]`. Unfortunately, this seemed to actually slow things down, presumably due to needing to store that intermediate value in memory.

Comment: This is an interesting but very complicated problem. Before anybody wastes their time, **are you really sure that your implementation is correct?**

Comment: Actually, the pseudocode from Wikipedia is very vague. For example, it is not clear wether the additions to P done within the for loop over Y have to be cycled through in the same for loop. When I look into papers that describe the algorithm, I see that stacks are applied there. But you cycle only once through the lists `inW` and `notinW`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm pretty sure that it at least gives the correct output---I can add in another couple test cases. In particular, I have an implementation to find the same result based on an alternative algorithm (which goes through finding the graph label product and then finding strongly connected components) from which I get the same final results. That algorithm is unfortunately $O(n^2)$ and is a huge memory hog. If there is an error in my code, I am almost certain that it would be getting too many sets in the waiting set $W$ that need to be split by.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher As for your second question, I'm not quite following. I have `While[... Do[ X = ...; inW= ...; notinW=...; ..., {index, Length@alphabet}] ]`, so the sets `inW` and `notinW` get recomputed multiple times (based on the current splitter `toPartBy` and the current edge label implied by `index`

Comment: I mean the `for each set Y in P for which` loop. Depending on the interpretation of the pseudocode, this could be a loop that _cannot_ be implemented with `Table` and that needs some more sophisticated way of queueing. I just meant to say that it would be great have some assurances for correctness. Speaking only for me, the algorithm is a bit too complicated to understand it right from the beginning and I have to operate solely on the code level. By the way, I did not mean to criticize your post. Actually, it is very well written! (+1)

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher ah, I understand your question now---thanks for the reply. It's definitely a beast of an algorithm...I think it took me multiple sessions over a week of working examples by hand, and then another week of a faithful implementation with numerous `Echo[` commands to figure out what the heck was going on. The key for me was that everything inside the `for each set Y in P for which .... ;` loop involves replacing or appending entries in `P` and `W`. (ct'd)

Comment: (ct'd) In other words, suppose that for some `Y in P` we get `False` from `Intersection[Y,X] != {} && Complement[Y,X] != {}`. Then `Y` should just be left alone in `P` (along with in `W` if it happens to be an element there). However, I took care of this by just replacing `Y` in `P` (and perhaps `W`) by `{Intersection[Y,X], Complement[Y,X]}`, which will be off the form `{Y, {}}`. Upon later flattenings and `DeleteCases[..., {}]`, the net result is replacing `Y` with `Y`. Thanks again for taking a look!

Comment: A brief perusal suggests that your implentation is O(n^2) or maybe O(n^2 log n), because there are O(n log n) operations in the main loop. `Intersection`, `Complement`, etc. all behave this way. If the idea is to add or remove a few elements from a large set, this will need to be done in a different way in orfder to get the desired complexity.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well.....f##$*&. I'll edit and post up a faithful, logical version